# How to manipulate a generated CSS

Tags: javascript, angular, css, css-selectors

I have this css style which is generated from Angular module so I can't do anything there.

The problem is that I want to -30px from what is generated.

```
<div ng2-sticky="" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: static; float: none; top: auto; bottom: auto; width: 1040px; left: auto;">
     Hello World
</div>
```

As the value changes with screen size, I want the width to be 30px lesser always. So for this specific screen size, it should be `1010px`.

I'm not sure how I could possibly use `calc` here or is there any other method to achieve this?

PS: I can't edit the Javascript generating this code since it's not on my server.

Comment: You could listen to the resize event and modify the width accordingly

Comment: `width: calc(100vw - 30px)` (with of window - 30px) or `width: calc(100% - 30px)` (width of container - 30px)

Answer (score 1):

**JS** - You can do something like this in js

```
let element = document.querySelector('div[ng2-sticky]'); 
let width = element.offsetWidth;

let newWidth = width - 30 + "px";
element.style.width = newWidth;
```

**CSS** - or simple trick in css would be

```
div[ng2-sticky]{

  margin: 0 15px;

}
```

so it would give a margin to the left and right

Answer (score 0):

you could

```
document.querySelector('[ng2-sticky=""]').style.width = 1010px;
```

or perhaps

```
<style>div[ng2-sticky=""] {width:1010px !important;}</style>
```

Comment: You've mistaken my query. That width is responsive so it changes as i change the screen size. What i need is to -30px the generated width. So if it is 1040px, it should be 1010px or if it 930px, it should be 900px. 30px must always be subtracted.

Comment: Then with your limited options, I believe you need to use javascript and run it every time a resize occurs...pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGoKaJ